# Insert a value into SQL local database and print the tables data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, cordova

I have a form which uses html and javascript to submit data into a table of an SQL database. So I want to submit what is typed from the user to a local SQLite database that is inside his device. I am using PhoneGap so I can only use HTML, JavaScript ans CSS. I have the data inserted with a value called `SubmVal` . I want to insert that value into a table called TEST and has just two fields [id `INT NOT NULL`-name `VARCHAR`]. I use this code:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova TEST", 20000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

function SubmitButton() {
    /*
    CODE TO GET THE INSERTED DATA
    */
    var SubmVal = submitteddata;
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this ' + SubmVal + ' into the database?')) {
                 function populateDB(tx) {
                 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name) VALUES (1, SubmVal)');
                 }
                 alert("Succesfully Inserted");
    } else {
                 alert("Cancelled");
    }

}
```

So I have 3 questions:
1. How to get the SubmVal into the second field of the table? I am pretty sure this one doesn't work:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name) VALUES (1, SubmVal)');
```

2. How to get this `populateDB(tx)` function working, like a physical continuation(not to press other buttons or stuff). Do I need to change the code like this:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this ' + SubmVal + ' into the database?')) {
                     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name) VALUES (1, SubmVal)');}
```

3. How can I print every single line of the table using a function?

I made the question a bit more general in order to help as many as possible people who have the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basic javascript strings:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name) VALUES (1, SubmVal)');
                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

Since `SubmVal` is inside a string, Javascript treats it like everything else inside the string - some text. That means you're telling the DB engine to insert a value from a non-existent field.

You want

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (id, name) VALUES (1, ' + SubmVal + ')');
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so that you're concatenating your JS variable into the SQL string.

And note that this sort of construct leaves you open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

If `SubmVal` is non-numeric, it'll have to be quoted as well.